# RPG program parm change impact analysis

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpg

I have a situation where an RPG program used as an API needs to be modified. I am trying to do an impact analysis of this change to avoid any errors in dependant programs.

So, the program has two parameters. Both these parms are data structures.

The requirement is to add one new field to the input parm DS and one field to the output parm DS.

The API program (which is being changed) entry is defined as this:

```
dcl-pi;
    InputDS    likeds(API901INP);
    OutputDS   likeds(API901OUP);
end-pi;
```

Below is an example of how the input and output DS's in the API program are defined and how they are going to be changed by adding the new field:

```
dcl-ds InputDS extname('901_i);
    NameOfCandidate extfld('name');
    JobOfCandidate extfld('job'); --> newly added field
    AgeOfCandidate extfld('age');
end-ds;

dcl-ds OutputDS extname('901_o');
    AgeQualified extfld('qualified');
    JobCertified extfld('certified'); --> newly added field
end-ds
```

As can be seen, the standard we use requires API DS structures to be defined as an external structure. Which means, if a new field is to be added as above, the reference tables (901_i/901_o)
would need to be modified first.

Also, when this API is called from within other programs, the DS would have to be defined using the reference files.

Now, the question is not all programs calling the API need the new field added to the DS. So, would the existing programs be impacted by this change?

And to repeat, the existing programs also use the same external reference files (901_i/901_o) to define the datastructure parms to be used when calling the API program.
So, would they (calling programs which dont add the new field in output and input DS) need a change of some sort, say recompilation etc ?

Update:
The above was just a simplified example of what I need to do. Below is the actual code.

This is how the input DS is defined in the API rpg.

```
dcl-ds P_IAC3003I                          extname('IAC3003_I') qualified template;
    ExternSessionId                          extfld('EXTSESSID');
    WorkKey                                  extfld('WORKKEY');
    PreferedReferenceType                    extfld('PREFREF');
    SalesCountryCode                         extfld('SALESCNTRY');
    ManufacturingCountryCode                 extfld('MANUFCNTRY');
    TypeOfPerformanceUsage                   extfld('PERFUSE');
    TypeOfMechanicalUsage                    extfld('MECHUSE');
    UsageDateChar                            extfld('USAGEDATE');
    DistributionDateChar                     extfld('DISTRDATE');
    PerfIPRight                              extfld('PERFRIGHT');
    MechIPRight                              extfld('MECHRIGHT');
    DistributingSociety                      extfld('DISTRSOC');
    TypeOfAction                             extfld('SAVEACTION');
    UserPermission                           extfld('USERPERM');
    ExpertMode                               extfld('EXPERTMDE');
    LimitAccessToSociety                     extfld('LMTACCSSOC'); //new field
    GetNoOfRows                              extfld('GETNOOFROW');
  end-ds;
```

The new field (LimitAccessToSociety) was not added as the last field as by convention, the getNumberOfRows is always passed as the last parm (I think it makes cosmetic sense to maintain it that way).

This is how a caller would call the RPG:

```
callp IAC3003 (IACSESSION:
                  IAC3003I:
                  IACRETMSG:
                  IAC3003D:
                  IAC3003L1:
                  IACRESLIST01:
                  IAC3003L2:
                  IACRESLIST02:
                  IAC3003L3:
                  IACRESLIST03);
```

The first parm being the one to which the new field is to be added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem if you don't want to compile every program that calls the API program is that the callee has to know if the caller knows about the new field or not, otherwise the callee maybe fail if the age parameter has to be numeric, at least would not use the age as the caller passed it and maybe would corrupt the caller memory which could hide the real problem behind a exception in the caller.

You could add a third parameter that tells the version of the API with `options(*nopass)`, and when the parameter is not set (`%parms = 2`) act like it was set to the orginal version

But the problem is that the new field in the input parameter is not added at the end, so next compilation of the caller has to have the new parameter passed and set because the new input structure is used and the age value has moved.

I'm not sure it's worth the effort.

Edit :

> how does the ds field values get passed correctly after recompile ?

Since the structure is defined after IAC3003_I, an external file, every change to the file makes the structure change in every program that is compiled after the file is changed, and only when the program is compiled

Comment: Thanks @nfgl!. As you mentioned, I found that the API indeed fails with a decimal data error and the last parameter seems to have junk value. This is fixed by a recompilation of the caller program. Please see updated question for more details. Now, my next question is how does recompilation solve the issue ? I mean the API is called using callp (PR defined with extpgm) so how does the ds field values get passed correctly after recompile ? Also, there are just 3 programs calling the API. so the effort is not really much involved in recompilation. But does recompilation really solve the issue?

Comment: HELLO @nfgl. I was actually confused seeing caller programs where the input DS is defined using  EXTPGM('IAC3003_I') and all subfields except the new one defined using EXTFLD calling the API without errors after recompiling. As I understand now, even if the new subfield is not explicitly defined using EXTFLD, it is still added as a "hidden" field in the DS. This I could see in the compile listing. I was under the impression that if a subfield is not explicitly declared using extfld, it would not be part of the DS created on program compilation. Could you share your thought on my understanding?

Comment: Other thing I noticed is, even if the ordering of the subfields are changed, on compilation, the DS is still created with the same structure as the external table!! So EXTNAME is not just for the sake of reference as I am discovering now!

Comment: @Theju112 Yes, all fields in the file are here. Think of it as a /COPY that is generated on the fly using the current structure of the file, and EXTFLD lines just rename the fields.

Comment: I think I understand you  but wanna confirm.. can you really say "on the fly" as it sounds more like run time rather than compile time ? If the structure was dynamically referred during run time, there wouldn't be any need to re-compile right ?  Please confirm.

Comment: No, sorry that caused confusion, it's done at compile time, changes in the file structure don't matter at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

One choice is to consider rather altering an existing API, write a new one. Name it APIv2 or something. Now you can leave all of the existing consumers alone unless they actually need the new field.

If your group are resistant to altering this 'single version of an API' pattern, one could create a second DS for the new (and now, optional) 'parameter'. Make that one nopass, and then the callers will be able to ignore it when they don't need it. Use %parms in the API to know when this new DS/parameter was in fact passed in by the caller.

Comment: Hi @buck, thanks for the great suggestion! but as you said there might be resistance to two versions considering that it would lead to double work in the event of a future maintenance. Adding a second DS definitely makes sense. But in this case, luckily the API RPG is just called by a handful of programs and a simple recompile of these caller programs makes more sense to me.. your thoughts please

Comment: One can avoid the 'double work' scenario by rewriting the v1 API to be nothing more than a shell that calls the v2 API with the 'optional' parameter accounted for.